# Conditional column using threshold values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a table set up as follows:

```
Name    ScoreA    ScoreB    
Jimmy   0.95       0.95       
Claire  0.95       0.75
```

What I would like to do is is have an output column that returns 1 if both scores are above 0.9, returns 0 if both scores are below 0.8 and returns 2 if both scores are within 0.8 < score < 0.9 OR if one score is above 0.9 and the other is below 0.9.

The output would look something like this:

```
Name    ScoreA    ScoreB   0/1/2  
Jimmy    0.95      0.95      1
Claire   0.65      0.75      0
Harry    0.85      0.82      2
Paige    0.91      0.82      2
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['0/1/2'] = np.select([(df.ScoreA<.8)&(df.ScoreB<.8), (df.ScoreA>.9)&(df.ScoreB>.9)], [0,1], 2)
```

Result:

```
     Name  ScoreA  ScoreB  0/1/2
0   Jimmy    0.95    0.95      1
1  Claire    0.65    0.75      0
2   Harry    0.85    0.82      2
3   Paige    0.91    0.82      2
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!